# Gray Code for Combinations

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

> **Question:**
>   are Gray Codes known for enumerating all fixed-size subsets of a given finite set?

Background of the question is trying to find the lightest k-clique in a symmetric TSP instance of size n in the most efficient way.
Without being able to utilize Gray Coding one has to perform $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ additions per clique to determine its weight; with Gray Coding that effort can be reduced to $k-1$ subtractions and $k-1$ additions for updating the weight after one of the clique's vertices has been exchanged by a different one that isn't already in that clique.

Comment: The top answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n may be helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the pointer; the article http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/EHR/HoughRuskey.pdf would be an acceptable answer to my question